# unexpected token node.js v8.9.4

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just starting out learning node.js (v8.9.4) and I created a simple web server. I am getting the following syntax error message. I understand the => operator is a recent addition to node.js, however I am using the latest stable version. Has anyone else ran into this? Does anyone have any suggestions on things to try to resolve this? The javascript file I am trying to run is below the error message.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3


const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.send('Hello World');
}).listen(3000);

console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a function keyword in `function(req, res)`

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem here:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) => {
```

Remove the `function` keyword, or remove the `=>`.  Only one of the two is needed.

```
(args) => { return do-something-with-args; }
```

is equivalent to

```
function(args) { return do-something-with-args; }
```

There are differences in arrow functions and old-style functions having to do with the definition of `this` inside the function, but they're not important for your question.  In short, `this` in an arrow function is scoped to the block in which the arrow function is declared (in this case your module,) where with an old-style `function`, `this` is scoped to the function itself.

For reference, arrow functions are not particularly "new" to NodeJS.  They have been around since ~2015 (v 4.4.5 I think.)

Answer (score 1):

Try without the function keyword:

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.send('Hello World');
}).listen(3000);
```